# Poner más de un delimitador en la función fgetcsv()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Buenas a todos necesito ayuda para leer un csv

```
$csv = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $file = fopen($csv,"r"); // Lee el csv
     $row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ","); //get row values
```

Este es mi código donde recibo los headers de un csv desde angular, necesito poner más de un delimitador para que pueda leer si el csv viene con ; gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Te refieres a tener dos delimitadores distintos al mismo tiempo? Me parece que no es posible. Lo que puedes hacer es reemplazar uno de ellos, para trabajar con un solo delimitador.

Comment: Lo resolví haciendo a elegir al usuario si su archivo csv es por "," o ";" pero me dijeron que no es lo ideal, aún sigo trabado con esa parte :/